# how to set touch event only on specified View

Tags: iphone, ipad

how to get a touch event only on specified view.Not on other view

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


       UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
       currentPoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];

}
```

In this code touch is on  anyObject.

is there any why i can give touches to only specifies view.

Comment: can you explain a little more specifically what you are trying to do?

Comment: @KyleRosenbluth  I do have 3 UIView in my controller.  I want touch events only on first uiview if i am touches another uiview the     touchBegin,touchEnded and touchMoved are calling.  I do not want call them when i touches another view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property view on the UITouch, to find which view it occurred on

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIView *view
```

[UITouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITouch)

Or you can find all the touched for a particular view, from the UIEvent param

```
- (NSSet *)touchesForView:(UIView *)view
```

[UIEvent](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html)